# Почему не отображается видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не могу понять, почему не встраивается видео на сайт. Вот код:

```
<div id="video-wrap-footer">

    </div>

var windowRes = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
function videoAdd() {
  if (windowRes > 1023) {   
    document.getElementById('video-wrap-footer').innerHTML = '<video autoplay id="bgvid_footer" poster="img/water-on-glass.jpg"><source src="videos/medoff-video.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="videos/medoff-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>';
  }
}


video#bgvid, video#bgvid_footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Я вижу его в коде, через веб-инспектор, но в браузере нет

Comment: Что в переменной windowRes?

Comment: @Kison, прошу прощения, обновил ответ

Comment: Вы уверены, что (windowRes > 1023) истина?

Comment: @Kison Уверен))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ НАЙДЕНО
Проблема была в плагине, который сбивал позиционирование и видео "клеилось" к хидеру. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');

    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;

    element.appendChild(source);
}

var video = document.createElement('video');
document.body.appendChild(video);
addSourceToVideo(video, 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv', 'video/ogg');

video.play();
```

Взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192098/adding-sources-to-html5-video-in-javascript)